# Django inline data save but i use for loop that way data overwrite save what to do?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

`Django` inline data save overwrite MCX i tried to save multiple data.

This is my main model (parent model):

```
class DebitClient(SysFields):
    debit_client_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, db_column='DEBIT_CLIENT_ID',
                                       verbose_name='Debit Client Id')
    from_date = models.DateField(db_column="FROM_DATE", verbose_name="From Date")
```

**I use here save method:**

```
   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        if not self.debit_client_id:
            formatted_date = self.from_date.strftime('%d%m%Y')
            self.debit_client_id = f'BB{formatted_date}'
            super(DebitClient, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

            from AtsERP.atserp_base.atserp_models.atserp_basemodels.atserp_accounting_models.basemodel_ledger.atserp_bm_client_ledger import \
                ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed
            from AtsERP.atserp_base.atserp_models.atserp_basemodels.atserp_settings_models.basemodel_organization.ats_bm_organization import \
                Organization
            from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

            net_debit_client_date = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active')).filter(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]).values('trade_date').first()

            start_date = net_debit_client_date['trade_date']
            print(start_date, "start date")

            start_obj_date_debit = \
                ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | \
                                        Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'))).aggregate(
                    debit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_debits'), 0)
                )['debit_sum']

            start_obj_date_credit = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[ "AC031", "A0001", 10795]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | \
                                    Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                    fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'))).aggregate(
                credit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_credits'), 0)
            )['credit_sum']

            start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | \
                                    Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                    fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active')) & Q(org_unit='CD_NSE')).aggregate(
                debit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_debits'), 0)
            )['debit_sum']

            start_obj_date_credit_cd_nse = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | \
                                    Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                    fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'), org_unit='CD_NSE')).aggregate(
                credit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_credits'), 0)
            )['credit_sum']

            total_cd_nse = start_obj_date_credit_cd_nse - start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse

            if start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse is None:
                start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse = 0
            print(start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse, "start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse")

            if start_obj_date_debit is None:
                start_obj_date_debit = 0
            if start_obj_date_credit is None:
                start_obj_date_credit = 0

            net_closing_balance = start_obj_date_credit - start_obj_date_debit

            print(start_obj_date_debit, "posted_debits")
            print(start_obj_date_credit, "posted_credits")

            print(net_closing_balance)

            target_date = self.from_date
            obj = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                Q(trade_date=target_date) | Q(trade_date__isnull=True)).filter(
                fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active')).filter(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"])

            fo_bill_dr = obj.filter(Q(doc_type="Bill") & Q(narration__icontains='BILL ENTRY FOR')& Q(org_unit='MCX')).aggregate(
                debit_sum=Sum('posted_debits'))
            fo_bill_cr = obj.filter(Q(doc_type="Bill") & Q(narration__icontains='BILL ENTRY FOR')& Q(org_unit='MCX')).aggregate(
                credit_sum=Sum('posted_credits'))

            fo_bill_debit = fo_bill_dr['debit_sum']
            fo_bill_credit = fo_bill_cr['credit_sum']

            if fo_bill_credit is None:
                fo_bill_credit = 0
            if fo_bill_debit is None:
                fo_bill_debit = 0

            fo_bill_total = fo_bill_credit - fo_bill_debit

            print(fo_bill_total, "fo_bill_total")

            obj_bill = obj.aggregate(debit_sum=Sum('posted_debits'))
            obj_bill_debit = obj_bill['debit_sum']
            print(obj_bill_debit, "posted_debits")

            obj_bill = obj.aggregate(credit_sum=Sum('posted_credits'))
            obj_bill_credit = obj_bill['credit_sum']

            print(obj_bill_credit, "posted_credits")

            # doc_type = obj.filter(doc_type='')

            df = pd.DataFrame(obj.values())
            print(df, "df")
            print(df.keys(), "df")

            df_group = df.groupby(["ledger_id", "org_unit_id"], as_index=False).agg(
                {"ledger_id": "first", "org_unit_id": "first", "posted_credits": "sum", "posted_debits": "sum"})

            # x = df.groupby("ending_balance").last()

            ledger_ids = ["AC031", "A0001", "1001", "1002", "1003", "10795"]
            start_obj_date_credit_mcx = {}
            start_obj_date_debit_mcx = {}

            for ledger_id in ledger_ids:
                if ledger_id.isdigit():
                    ledger_id = int(ledger_id)
                else:
                    ledger_id = str(ledger_id)

                start_obj_date_credit_mcx[ledger_id] = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id=ledger_id) & (
                            Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'), org_unit='MCX')
                ).aggregate(credit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_credits'), 0))['credit_sum']

                start_obj_date_debit_mcx[ledger_id] = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id=ledger_id) & (
                            Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'), org_unit='MCX')
                ).aggregate(debit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_debits'), 0))['debit_sum']

            for ledger_id in ledger_ids:
                if ledger_id.isdigit():
                    ledger_id = int(ledger_id)
                else:
                    ledger_id = str(ledger_id)

                credit_total = start_obj_date_credit_mcx[ledger_id]
                debit_total = start_obj_date_debit_mcx[ledger_id]

                # print(f"Ledger ID: {ledger_id}, Credit-Debit Total: {credit_total - debit_total}")

            if start_obj_date_credit_mcx is None:
                start_obj_date_credit_mcx = 0
            if start_obj_date_debit_mcx is None:
                start_obj_date_debit_mcx = 0

            for i in range(len(df_group)):
                # posted_credits = df.loc[i, "posted_credits"]
                # posted_debits = df.loc[i, "posted_debits"]
                ledger = df.loc[i, "ledger_id"]
                org_unit_id = df.loc[i, "org_unit_id"]

                # if posted_credits is None:
                #     posted_credits = 0
                # if posted_debits is None:
                #     posted_debits = 0

                start_obj_date_debit_nse_cash = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) | Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active')) & Q(org_unit='NSE_CASH')).aggregate(
                    debit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_debits'), 0)
                )['debit_sum']

                start_obj_date_credit_nse_cash = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) |
                                        Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'), org_unit='NSE_CASH')).aggregate(
                    credit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_credits'), 0)
                )['credit_sum']

                total_nse_cash = start_obj_date_credit_nse_cash - start_obj_date_debit_nse_cash

                start_obj_date_debit_bse_cash = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) |
                                        Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active')) & Q(org_unit='BSE_CASH')).aggregate(
                    debit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_debits'), 0)
                )['debit_sum']

                start_obj_date_credit_bse_cash = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) |
                                        Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'), org_unit='BSE_CASH')).aggregate(
                    credit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_credits'), 0)
                )['credit_sum']

                total_bse_cash = start_obj_date_credit_bse_cash - start_obj_date_debit_bse_cash

                start_obj_date_debit_nse_fno = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) |
                                        Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active')) & Q(org_unit='NSE_FNO')).aggregate(
                    debit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_debits'), 0)
                )['debit_sum']

                start_obj_date_credit_nse_fno = ClientLedgerTransactionDetailed.objects.filter(
                    Q(ledger__ledger_id__in=[10795, "AC031", "A0001"]) & (Q(trade_date__lte=self.from_date) |
                                        Q(trade_date__isnull=True)) & Q(
                        fin_year=FinancialYear.objects.get(status='Active'), org_unit='NSE_FNO')).aggregate(
                    credit_sum=Coalesce(Sum('posted_credits'), 0)
                )['credit_sum']

                total_nse_fno = start_obj_date_credit_nse_fno - start_obj_date_debit_nse_fno
                fo_bill_total_str = np.abs(fo_bill_total)

                # balance = posted_credits - posted_debits
                UNC_payment = 0  # @todo
                UNC_receipt = 0  # @todo
                net_closing = net_closing_balance + fo_bill_total + fo_bill_total + UNC_payment - UNC_receipt
                # if balance > 0:
                # print(balance, ledger)
                inline_model = DebitClientItems()
                inline_model.debit_client = DebitClient.objects.get(debit_client_id=self.debit_client_id)
                inline_model.client = ledger
                inline_model.account_code = ledger
                # inline_model.net_closing = net_closing
                inline_model.exchange = Organization.objects.get(org_unit_id=org_unit_id)

                if inline_model.exchange.org_unit_id == 'CD_NSE':
                    if start_obj_date_credit == 0 or start_obj_date_credit == '-':
                        inline_model.day_closing = start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse
                        inline_model.net_closing = start_obj_date_debit_cd_nse + fo_bill_total_str + UNC_payment - UNC_receipt
                    else:
                        inline_model.day_closing = total_cd_nse
                        inline_model.net_closing = total_cd_nse + fo_bill_total_str + UNC_payment - UNC_receipt
                elif inline_model.exchange.org_unit_id == 'MCX':
                    inline_model.day_closing = Decimal(0)
                    inline_model.net_closing = Decimal(0)
                    total_mcx_sum = Decimal(0)
                    total_mcx_list = []
                    inline_model.day_closing = []
                    for ledger_id in ledger_ids:
                        if isinstance(ledger_id, str) and ledger_id.isdigit():
                            ledger_id_int = int(ledger_id)
                        else:
                            ledger_id_int = ledger_id
                        credit_total = start_obj_date_credit_mcx.get(ledger_id_int, 0)
                        debit_total = start_obj_date_debit_mcx.get(ledger_id_int, 0)
                        total_mcx = credit_total - debit_total
                        total_mcx_sum += total_mcx
                        inline_model.day_closing = total_mcx
                        print(sum(total_mcx_list))
                elif inline_model.exchange.org_unit_id == 'NSE_CASH':
                    if start_obj_date_credit == 0 or start_obj_date_credit == '-':
                        inline_model.day_closing = start_obj_date_debit_nse_cash
                    else:
                        inline_model.day_closing = total_nse_cash
                elif inline_model.exchange.org_unit_id == 'BSE_CASH':
                    if start_obj_date_credit == 0 or start_obj_date_credit == '-':
                        inline_model.day_closing = start_obj_date_debit_bse_cash
                    else:
                        inline_model.day_closing = total_bse_cash
                elif inline_model.exchange.org_unit_id == 'NSE_FNO':
                    if start_obj_date_credit == 0 or start_obj_date_credit == '-':
                        inline_model.day_closing = start_obj_date_debit_nse_fno
                    else:
                        inline_model.day_closing = total_nse_fno
                inline_model.unc_payment = UNC_payment
                inline_model.unc_receipt = UNC_receipt

                inline_model.save()
```

Problem when I save MCX data:

```
inline_model.exchange.org_unit_id == 'MCX':
```

That time overwrite the for loop I got only last value of day_closing. I want there save every value one by one.

Here is my inline model:

```
class DebitClientItems(SysFields):
    debit_client = models.ForeignKey(DebitClient, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True,
                                     verbose_name='Debit Client', db_column='debit_client')
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column='CLIENT', verbose_name='Client')
    exchange = models.ForeignKey('Organization', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True,
                                 db_column='exchange',
                                 verbose_name='Exchange')
    account_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column='ACCOUNT_CODE',
                                    verbose_name='Account Code')
    day_closing = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, db_column="DAY_CLOSING",
                                   verbose_name="Day Closing")
    eq_bills = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="EQ_BILLS",
                                verbose_name="Eq Bills")
    fo_bills = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="FO_BILLS",
                                verbose_name="Fo Bills")
    unc_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="UNC_RECEIPT",
                                   verbose_name="Unc Receipt")
    unc_payment = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="unc_payment",
                                   verbose_name="Unc Payment")
    net_closing = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="NET_CLOSING",
                                   verbose_name="Net Closing")
    debit_margin = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="DEBIT_MARGIN",
                                    verbose_name="Debit Margin")
    not_to_export = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                     db_column="NOT_TO_EXPORT",
                                     verbose_name="Not To Export")
    future_eq_bills = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                       db_column="FUTURE_EQ_BILLS",
                                       verbose_name="Future Eq Bills")
    future_fo_bills = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                       db_column="FUTURE_FO_BILLS",
                                       verbose_name="Future Fo Bills")
    peak_ledger = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, db_column="PEAK_LEDGER",
                                   verbose_name="Peak Ledger")
    epi_crediting_ledger = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                            db_column="EPI_CREDITING_LEDGER",
                                            verbose_name="Epi Crediting Ledger")
    pool_stk_credit = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                       db_column="POOL_STK_CREDIT",
                                       verbose_name="Pool Stk Credit")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'debit_client_items'
        app_label = 'atserp_base'
```

My admin.py

```
class DebitClientItemsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DebitClientItems
        fields = '__all__'




class DebitClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DebitClient
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DebitClientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class DebitClientItemsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DebitClientItems
    show_change_link = False
    showOriginal = False
    max_num = 30
    can_delete = True
    # extra = 30
    fields = (
        'client',
        'exchange', 'account_code', 'day_closing', 'eq_bills',
        'fo_bills', 'unc_receipt', 'unc_payment', 'net_closing',
        'debit_margin', 'not_to_export', 'future_eq_bills', 'future_fo_bills',
        'peak_ledger', 'epi_crediting_ledger', 'pool_stk_credit',
    )

    # readonly_fields = ()

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj):
        pass


class DebitClientAdmin(ATSERPCustomAdminModel):
    # form = DebitClientForm
    form = DebitClientItemsForm
    inlines = [DebitClientItemsInline]



    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if '_Generate' in request.POST:
            url = reverse('debitclient',
                          kwargs={'mode': 'DEBIT_CLIENT', 'dobg': obj.from_date, 'pkobg': obj, 'ckobg': None})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super(DebitClientAdmin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)
        self.list_display = ['debit_client_id', 'from_date', ]
        self.list_filter = ('debit_client_id',)
        self.fields = ('debit_client_id', 'from_date',)
        self.search_fields = ('debit_client_id',)
        self.readonly_fields = ('debit_client_id',)
```

**I want save every mcx data like total_credir - total_debit**